# Screen size based tooltip with offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tooltip

Hi guys im trying to make a tooltip window for some items in the game im making. And for the love of god i cant figure out how to setup a screen based offset for the tooltip. Atm im using this (code no.1) after 2 sec turns on the tooltip gameobject (called StatDisplay) and it works on 16x9 resolution but after changing the resolution the tooltip is too far away from the main object. I tried it with mouse position (code 2) and im running into the same problem with the offset, its decreasing on higher resolutions and in smaller ones the offset is too big. Any ideas on how to fix this ? (i was thinking about making a variable that changes based on screen size but cant figure out a way...)

Code 1:

```
    bool hovering = false;
    public GameObject StatDisplay;



    IEnumerator StartCountdown()
    {
        RectTransform rc = StatDisplay.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        RectTransform rc2 = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        int time = 1;
        while ((time > 0) && (hovering == true))
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
            time--;
        }
        if ((time == 0) && (hovering == true))
        {

            if (Input.mousePosition.x > (Screen.width / 2))
            {
                if (Input.mousePosition.y > (Screen.height / 2))
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Top right");

                    StatDisplay.transform.position = new Vector3(-rc.rect.width / 2 + this.transform.position.x + rc2.rect.width / 2, -rc.rect.height / 2 + this.transform.position.y - rc2.rect.height / 2, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Bottom right");
                    StatDisplay.transform.position = new Vector3(- rc.rect.width / 2 + this.transform.position.x + rc2.rect.width / 2, rc.rect.height / 2 + this.transform.position.y + rc2.rect.height / 2, 0);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.mousePosition.y > (Screen.height / 2))
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Top Left");

                    StatDisplay.transform.position = new Vector3(rc.rect.width / 2 + this.transform.position.x - rc2.rect.width / 2, - rc.rect.height / 2 + this.transform.position.y - rc2.rect.height / 2, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Bottom Left");

                    StatDisplay.transform.position = new Vector3(rc.rect.width / 2 + this.transform.position.x - rc2.rect.width / 2, rc.rect.height / 2 + this.transform.position.y + rc2.rect.height / 2, 0);
                }
            }
            StatDisplay.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void Enter()
    {
        hovering = true;
        StartCoroutine(StartCountdown());
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        hovering = false;
        StatDisplay.SetActive(false);

    }
```

Code 2:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HoverAtCursorPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    RectTransform rt;
    CanvasGroup cg;

    float Obwidth;
    float Obheight;

    Vector3 MousePoz = new Vector3();

    private void Start()
    {
        rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        cg = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PositionFunction();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        cg.alpha = 0;
    }


    void Update()
    {

        Obwidth = rt.rect.width + 20f;
        Obheight = rt.rect.height + 20f;

        //Debug.Log("X: " + Screen.width / rt.rect.width);
        //Debug.Log("Y: " + Screen.height / rt.rect.height);

        MousePoz = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        PositionFunction();

        if (cg.alpha != 1)
        {
            if (gameObject.activeSelf == true)
            {
                cg.alpha += 0.1f;
            }
        }
    }


    void PositionFunction()
    {
        if (Input.mousePosition.x > (Screen.width / 2))
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.y > (Screen.height / 2))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Top right");

                transform.position = new Vector3(MousePoz.x * Screen.width - Obwidth / 2, MousePoz.y * Screen.height - Obheight / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.Log("Bottom right");
                transform.position = new Vector3(MousePoz.x * Screen.width - Obwidth / 2, MousePoz.y * Screen.height + Obheight / 2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.mousePosition.y > (Screen.height / 2))
            {
                //Debug.Log("Top Left");

                transform.position = new Vector3(MousePoz.x * Screen.width + Obwidth / 2, MousePoz.y * Screen.height - Obheight / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.Log("Bottom Left");

                transform.position = new Vector3(MousePoz.x * Screen.width + Obwidth / 2, MousePoz.y * Screen.height + Obheight / 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

class level var:
`bool isVis=false;`

```
void OnGUI(){
 if (isVis)
        {
    GUI.Box(new Rect(Input.mousePosition.x + 2, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y + 2, 128, 72), "Tool Tip Text");
               } 
    }



private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        isVis = true;

    }
    private void OnMouseExit()
    {
        isVis = false;

    }
```

throw this on your object you want a tool tip for, then you can make some adjustments. this will give you a box with the text "Tool Tip Text" at the mouse position, while you are mouse over the object. your object will need a collider.

more to the point of your question: you are looking for this line:

`new Rect(Input.mousePosition.x + 2, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y + 2, 128, 72)`

to get the correct y position in your endeavor you need to subtract the `mousePosition.y` from `Screen.Height`
its also important to note the `+2`, as if you draw right at the mouse it will stutter between the tooltip and the cursor

as i said below if you store the tool tip rect in a variable, thats set in Update()

in your OnGUI you can do this:

```
GUI.Box(myRect, "Tool Tip Text");
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(myRect.x,myRect.y+20,64,64),Resources.Load("Sprites/sample.png"))  ;
```

(the load method will grab the image, `sample.png` from your `Resources/Sprites` folder, if you dont have that folder you can make it, or change the path, but the path has to be in a folder called `Resources`

you can also do

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(myRect.x,myRect.y+84,myRect.width,24),"Item Description")) ;
```

the best part is, you can load a custom GUI skin, and set your own styles, and change each GUI element dynamically. this means  if you want a white title, and a gold description and a border around your image, it's a simple thing. if you want some sample styles let me know!

Comment: the problem with this approach is that i plan adding a image and some item stats (dmg,durability ect). Better explanation would be a hover text in inventory's like in world of warcraft or some other mmo's.

Comment: not a problem, set your rect to a variable: `Rect mytip =new Rect(Input.mousePosition.x + 2, Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y + 2, 128, 72)` then you can use it to add other GUI elements like textures or sprites, and other labels. you will want to adjust your rect according to what fits. ill update my answer with an example

Answer (score 0):

Ok while playing around i found a way to fix my code

```
rt = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        float RealWidth = rt.rect.width / Screen.width;
        float RealHeight = rt.rect.height / Screen.height;
```

rt is on the component thats has its anchor set to stretch on x and y (Rect transform > icon on the left > alt + icon at bottom right)

it seems like the real screen width and the width of the rect of an object are not the same even if its stretched to fit the whole screen. its always off by +-10-20% (not sure if its bc of canvas settings or what)... well whatever

```
new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x * RealWidth, Input.mousePosition.y * RealHeight, 0)
```

this vector will give you the right position on all the resolutions. well it does for me... it might help someone in with a similar problem